# https request semantic issue

Tags: https, request, client

I'm trying to make an https request from my node server to my main php server but it looks like the request isn't going through. I'm pretty sure there is an issue with the hostname line as I have read people having random issues with it but it could be something else. The php server is secured with ssl and is an amazon ec2.

```
exports.authenticate = function(request, callback) {
    var https = require('https');
    var options = {
            hostname: 'https://mysite.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/ajaxim/auth.php',
            method: 'GET',
            cookie: exports.cookie + '=' + request.sessionID
    };

    var req = https.request(options)

    req.end();

    req.on('response', function (response) {
            var data = '';
            response.setEncoding('utf8');
            response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    data += chunk;
            });

            //console.log (request.sessionID);

            response.on('end', function() {
                    try {
                            callback(JSON.parse(data));
                    } catch(e) {
                            callback();
                    }
            });
    });
};
```

Any suggestions will be insanely helpful. I'm just trying to get hint of the right direction.

Comment: you might want to try out your request with curl first

Comment: Is that simply typing curl -v mysite.com in the console of the node server? If so, it was able to connect.

Comment: You issue was about https so you might want to issue a https curl request

Comment: I  figured out the problem. I included the wrong directory for this file in my main program. Thanks for the advice though! I learned some things about curling.